# What exactly does 'git push heroku' push?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I got 9mb(last commit) app on git, it used to be a lot bigger. But after this:  git push -f heroku HEAD:master it pushes over 90mb app to server.I think it may be pushing some previous commits too... Can anyone tell me what actually happens and maybe how to fix it ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
git push heroku
```

pushes the current git branch to the remote repository configured at the name `heroku`. In this case, probably your Heroku app.

By default, it pushes the currently tracked branch, in general `master` (unless you are in a branch). Only the commits present in your branch and not available in the remote branch will be pushed. Non fast-forward commits will be rejected.

If you run

```
git push -f heroku HEAD:master
```

you are telling the push to override the content of the remote branch `master` with the content in your currently tracked branch, to the latest revision (`HEAD`).

The option `-f` forces the commit even if the history between your branch and the remote branch diverged at some time, effectively overriding the remote branch with the content of your branch.

This may be the cause. If for some reason the remove content differs from your local branch, your command may actually be pushing a lot of new data to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

"git push heroku" pushes only the your last commit.

if you want to get back to a previous release of your app, check the different releases of your app using :

```
heroku releases
```

then you can go back to another release of your app with :

```
heroku rollback vNN
```

***With NN being the number of your release**